# equivalent of hook_field_widget_form_alter() for field formatters?

Tags: entities

There's a hook hook_field_widget_form_alter() for altering a field widget, but I can't see anything equivalent for altering a field formatter's output.

Comment: There isn't a direct equivalent, but `hook_preprocess_field` is often enough, depending on the formatter - what type(s) are you looking to intercept?

Comment: If you want to alter the output of the field formatters as early as possible before any other processing and rendering starts, you can use [hook_entity_display_build_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_display_build_alter/9). I've linked the D9 version because the example code fits the question better than the D10 version.